# Enable ForceCheckOut on library in the elements.xml?

Tags: document-library

I created a new list instance in VS2015 and selected some contenttype. Now I would like to enable `ForceCheckOut` on this library. How can I do that? I know it is possible in c# code, but I do not want to create an eventreceiver. Is it also possible in the elements.xml?

This is my current elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="CustomDocuments" 
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE" 
                TemplateType="101" 
                Url="Lists/CustomDocuments" 
                Description="CustomDocuments" 
                VersioningEnabled="TRUE">
  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListInstance` element does not have any attribute to mention `ForceCheckOut` . Check this post about [ListInstance Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ms476062.aspx) to see the whole available attributes.

But `List` element do have `ForceCheckOut` (This `List` element is only available inside `Webtemplates` and not available if you want to deploy the list inside a normal site/web feature.) Check this post about [List Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543874.aspx)

```
<List
  CustomSchema = "Text"
  Description = "Text"
  EmailAlias = "Text"
  EnableContentTypes = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  EnableMinorVersions = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  FeatureId = "GUID"
  ForceCheckout = "TRUE" | "FALSE"  HyperlinkBaseUrl = Text
  QuickLaunchUrl = Text
  RootWebOnly = "TRUE" | "FALSE"
  Title = "Text"
  Type = Integer
  Url = "Text"
  VersioningEnabled = "TRUE" | "FALSE">
</List>
```

Comment: Where do I need to add this "List" element? I used the VS way to create a listinstance. So I have a schema.xml and elements.xml. And do I need to remove the current ListInstance element?

Comment: I think List element is only available if you are deploying a web template. In normal features like ListInstance this element will not be available.